# Hibernate one to many mapping with additional relation table

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I want to have two tables with one to many relation that are linked by third table. How can I approach this? I want to create exactly the same thing as in this [tutorial](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-many-1.html) but using one-to-many instead of many-to-many with unique="true"

Comment: Just create an entity for the third table. Instead of M-M of entity A<->B you want 1-M A->X and 1-M B->X. A B and X are all entities.

Comment: You can find many such examples online....

Comment: @balaji-reddy All of them are using only 2 tables without relation table.

Comment: @gerrytan Shouldn't it be M-1 B-> X? I want table A linked with B by 1-M relation using mapping table X with foreign keys for both A and B

Answer (score 2):

In Hibernate when you use a @OneToMany annotation without stating a @JoinTable or @JoinColumn a third table will be automatically created to map the relationship, so no worries in just switching the @ManyToMany by @OneToMany, as long you relationship will follow the rules of the annotation.

However, you can try some explicit mapping, so you will be able to control even de column names that will be created by the @OneToMany annotation.

Try something like this:

```
public class TestClass1 {

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "ADDITIONAL TABLE NAME", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "TESTCLASS1_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "TESTCLASS2_ID")})
    private List<TestClass2> listTestClass2;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I would like to do this without annotations.